# word count in graphlab vs sklearn

Tags: sklearn-pandas

Is there any function in pandas or sklearn like in graphlab-create "graphlab.text analytics.count_words" to count words of every row and make a new column in csv data sheet of word count ?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do it. The easiest solution is to use `Counter` :

```
from collections import Counter

data = {
    "Sentence" : ["Hello World", "The world is mine", "World is big", "Hello you", "foo_bar bar", "temp"],
    "Foo" : ["1000", "750", "500", "25000", "2000", "1"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  # create a fake dataframe

# Create a counter for every words
counter = Counter()

# update the counter with every rows of you dataframe
df["Sentence"].str.split(" ").apply(counter.update)

# You can check the result as a dict with counter.most_common() but if you want a dataframe you can do
pd.DataFrame(c.most_common(), columns = ["Word", "freq"])
```

Pay attention that you may have to pre-process text upfront (convert to lower, use a Stemmer, ...). For example with my test dataframe you have :

> {'Hello': 2,
>            'The': 1,
>            'World': 2,
>            'bar': 1,
>            'big': 1,
>            'foo_bar': 1,
>            'is': 2,
>            'mine': 1,
>            'temp': 1,
>            'world': 1,
>            'you': 1}

and you can see that you have "World" = 2 and "world" = 1 because I didn't convert to lower/upper the text.

You can also look at other solution like the `CountVectorizer` ([link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)) or again the `TF-IDF Vectorizer` ([link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer))

I hope it helps,

Nicolas